# electron-forge make results in Error: Could not find any make targets configured for the "win32" platform

Tags: electron, electron-forge

```
electron-forge make results in Error: Could not find any make targets configured for the "win32" platform.
with command:
PS E:\VStudio\20210417> npm run make2

> 20210417@1.0.0 make2
> electron-forge make 

✔ Checking your system
✔ Resolving Forge Config
We need to package your application before we can make it
✔ Preparing to Package Application for arch: x64
✔ Preparing native dependencies
✔ Packaging Application

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Could not find any make targets configured for the "win32" platform.
    at _default (E:\VStudio\20210417\node_modules\@electron-forge\core\src\api\make.ts:170:11)
    at E:\VStudio\20210417\node_modules\@electron-forge\cli\src\electron-forge-make.ts:44:5   

Electron Forge was terminated. Location:{}
```

Comment: content of package.json:
{
  [...]
    "make2": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "make_targets": {
        "win32": [
          "squirrel"
       [...]
      },
      [...]
   }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "electron": "^12.0.4"
  }
}

Comment: Have you configured electron-forge properly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You can't just dump your error here. We need context, ideally as a [mcve].

Answer (score 8):

It worked for me by removing and reinstalling the dependencies

```
npm install --save-dev @electron-forge/cli
npx electron-forge import
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was due to missing the `makers` configuration in my `forge.config.js` since I opted for using that instead of another property in the package.json.

When you run the `electron-forge import` command, it ends up configuring a bunch of makers:

```
  makers: [
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
    },
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
      config: {
        name: "my-app-here",
      },
    },
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
    },
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
    },
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the file "package-lock.json" worked for me.